# Prolog: Graph representation of list and difference list

Tags: list, prolog, difference-lists

I've been trying to understand how a list and a difference list would look like in a graph structure. I understand the basic structure of a list like [a1,a2,a3,..an|[]].

[image: arbitrary list]

But I can't grasp how a difference list would look like?

like for example [1,2,3,4]-[3,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Y` is the term `-(X, Y)`. So `[1,2,3,4]-[3,4]` is primarily just a pair of two lists, each of which can be readily displayed in a tree like the one you show.

Consider now a list of the form `[E1,E2,...,E_n|Rest]`, that is, where the final tail is not yet instantiated. Again, you can readily display this in a tree like the one you show, just replace `end-of-list` (which is wrong anyway, because it should actually be the atom nil: `[]`) by `Rest`.

The idea is now to always keep track of the tail that is not yet instantiated, which is a single logical variable. By instantiating this variable, again to a list whose tail is not yet instantiated and of whose tail you again keep track separately, you can always append further elements, *in time independent of the length that the original list has already reached*.

You can represent such a list and its final tail as the pair `[E1,E2,...,E_n|Rest]-Rest`, but it's actually preferable to use two different arguments and pass around the list and its uninstantiated final tail as two separate arguments ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276796/1613573)).